# What table are data directives stored in epicor

Tags: epicorerp

Where can I find the sql table that stores the data directives are stored?  I would like to know all the data directives that has been defined for in the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in version 9, the table is called `BpBaseProcDirective`.

Also, you can search for all of them in the GUI using the `Search by Directives` option in the search dialog in the `Data directives` window.

Answer (score 2):

In Epicor 10.0 and 10.1 these are defined in Ice.BpDirective.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Ice.BpDirective 
WHERE Source = 'DB' and Name <> '##BASE##'
```

With the design from the graphical designer stored as XML in the body field. Method directives are in the same table with a Source of 'BO'.